# UTF-8 works from browser not application

Tags: java, tomcat

This is the sample url

http://abc.com/ABCServlet/abc?cmd=1&id=123&content=%E8%AE%8A

From the browser i'm receiving 變 which is correct,

But from an application which does a http post using the same url I get  è®�. Seems like a double encoding or something, anyone has any ideas?

Comment: When you say you get those characters, at what point are you looking? Are you looking at the network traffic incoming, or a string in your Java string whilst debugging?

Comment: Show the app code which you use to read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get three characters, my guess is that you read the input stream without specifying an encoding.

Wrap the stream in `InputStreamReader( stream, "UTF-8" )` or, even better, get the encoding from the HTTP header (see the docs of your HTTP framework how to do that).

Comment: You are half right. That gave us a clue. The "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" was missing from the header when the application was posting. Now it's working! Thanks.